# Find $\frac{\partial \operatorname{trace}(AX^{-1}A^TX)}{\partial X}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, partial-derivative, trace

Assume $A$ is nonsingular and $X$ is symmetric, I want to find this derivative

\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial \operatorname{trace}(AX^{-1}A^TX)}{\partial X}.
\end{align}

In matrix cookbook I found this:

For symmetric $C$ we have

\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial \operatorname{trace}((X^TCX)^{-1}A)}{\partial X}=-(CX(X^TCX^{-1}))(A+A^T)(X^TCX)^{-1}.
\end{align}

Assuming that $X,C$ are nonsingular, and $C=A^{-T}$, $\operatorname{trace}((X^TCX)^{-1}A)=\operatorname{trace}(AX^{-1}A^TX^{-T})$, unfortunately a little bit different then what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the objective function as
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= AX^{-1}:XA \\
}$$
where the colon denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB) = {\rm Tr}(AB^T)$$
Then calculate the gradient
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= AX^{-1}:dX\,A + XA:A\,dX^{-1} \\
 &= AX^{-1}A^T:dX + A^TXA:dX^{-1} \\
 &= AX^{-1}A^T:dX - A^TXA:\big(X^{-1}\,dX\,X^{-1}\big) \\
 &= \big(AX^{-1}A^T - X^{-1}A^TXAX^{-1}\big):dX \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial X}
 &= AX^{-1}A^T - X^{-1}A^TXAX^{-1} \\
}$$
The cyclic property of the trace allow the terms in a Frobenius
product to be rearranged in a number of equivalent ways, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
&A:B = B:A = B^T:A^T \\
&A:BC = AC^T:B = C^T:A^TB \\
}$$